# apply specific command for each git repository

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, git

I want compress all the git repositories on my computer (say in `~`). I.e., for each directory `{}`, that contains directory or file (in case of submodules) named `.git`, I want to execute `git gc --aggressive --git-dir={}`.

I tried the following:

```
/bin/find /c/libs/boost/ -name '.git' -print -exec git --git-dir=dirname {} gc --aggressive \;
```

but output consist of plenty of `fatal: Not a git repository: 'dirname /c/libs/boost/.git'` etc. What should I do to use `dirname` command correctly? Or something else to achieve desired effect?

Comment: Also I tried `bash -c ""` with `\$\(dirname {}\)` and `\`dirname {}\``, but without any positive effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the word `dirname` as the argument to `--git-dir`.

With GNU or FreeBSD find, the `-execdir` action executes a command in the directory containing the matching file.

```
find /c/libs/boost/ -name '.git' -execdir git gc --aggressive \;
```

If your find command doesn't have `-execdir`, you can pass the `.git` directory as an argument to `--git-dir`.

```
find /c/libs/boost/ -name '.git' -exec git --git-dir {} gc --aggressive \;
```

In general, if you need shell expansion, invoke a shell explicitly, with `sh -c 'shell command'`. Don't attempt to perform any interpolation in the shell command, as that would fail with file names containing special characters. Pass the match(es) as an argument to the shell script. Note that after `sh -c 'shell command'`, the first argument is `$0`, and the other arguments (`$1`, `$2`, …) collectively form `"$@"`.

```
find /c/libs/boost/ -name '.git' -exec sh -c 'cd "${0%/.}" && git gc --aggressive' {} \;
find /c/libs/boost/ -name '.git' -exec sh -c 'for dir; do cd "${dir%/.}" && git gc --aggressive' _  {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for location in $( find -type d -name .git /path/to/base/of/search ); do
    if pushd "$location/.."; then
        git gc --aggressive --git-dir=.
        popd
    fi
done
```

Comment: Ough. Too wordy. I think about 1 loc solution.

Comment: It can be done on one line; I just broke it up so that you could easily follow the logic.

Comment: I know that you can delimit lines by means of `;`, but this is not the approach. I know, that many languages supports such style (one line of code), but I imply single statement here.

Comment: Won't work if a directory contains spaces or other special characters. Parsing the output of `find` is not a good idea, `-exec` is easier to control.

Comment: True, @Gilles, but I maintain that if you're putting spaces or other special characters in your directory or file names, you're doing it wrong. (:

Answer (score 1):

I find solution (works on `msys`):

```
/bin/find /c/libs/boost/ -name '.git' -print -exec bash -c 'cd $(dirname {}) ; git gc --aggressive' \; 2>&1 | tee git-gc.log
```

Comment: Note, that submodule directories contains `.git` files, unlike bare or working-tree repositories contains `.git` directories.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Instead, I want to see all the git repositories.